# Merge associate array's values php

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a short nice way(without using for/foreach) of merging associate array's values into one, mainly I need to convert this

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        (int) 0 => '1',
        (int) 1 => '4',
        (int) 2 => '5',
        (int) 3 => '12'
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        (int) 0 => '6'
    ),
    (int) 2 => array(
        (int) 0 => '7'
    ),
    (int) 3 => array(
        (int) 0 => '10'
    ),
    (int) 4 => array(
        (int) 0 => '11'
    ),
    (int) 5 => array(
        (int) 0 => '8'
    ),
    (int) 6 => array(
        (int) 0 => '9'
    )
)
```

to this

```
array(
    (int) 0 => '1',
    (int) 1 => '4',
    (int) 2 => '5',
    (int) 3 => '12'
    (int) 4 => '6'  
    (int) 5 => '7'
    (int) 6 => '10'
    (int) 7 => '11'
    (int) 8 => '8'
    (int) 9 => '9'  
)
```

THanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/call_user_func_array) with [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/array_merge) as the callback:

```
$result = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 5
    [3] => 12
    [4] => 6
    [5] => 7
    [6] => 10
    [7] => 11
    [8] => 8
    [9] => 9
)
```

Comment: Demo page is not working anymore

Comment: @LifeafterGuest Thanks. It looks like the site does not exist anymore. I've removed the link.